# Xcode, как отрисовать новые элементы при повороте экрана?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, интерфейс

в стандартном калькуляторе айфона, при повороте экрана появляются дополнительные клавиши, расширяющие возможности.
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать подобное?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите https://www.raywenderlich.com/1343912-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-12-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в свою форму, и опишите поведения вашего вью

```
   override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            // здесь код для landscape

        } else {
           //здесь код для portrait
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, то есть нужно добавить на форму к остальным элементам и отключить добавленные элементы, и включать при повороте?

Comment: Да, можно изменить констрейты, но в случае калькулятора их нужно добавлять элементы.